# Bootstrap - Can't get button to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, center

All I am trying to do is center a button on top of an image.  I've done this many times but something is really off here and I can't figure out what it is.  The button is centered with the image when it is not absolute.  I make it absolute so it goes on top of the image but then it is suddenly off center.

I have a Bootply example here: http://www.bootply.com/eHq2b3ydhH

I feel like I'm just not seeing something obvious but really have no idea what it is.

Comment: `bottom:45px;`  ? for at top aligned ?

Comment: I'd like it centered 45px from the bottom.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/Qmy2EzNAJt take a look,

Comment: That example does not have centered text.

Comment: I know, that's why it's not an answer but a reply; it show you why : the base centre is  the part in blue and as you are in absolute position, the 'middle' is just the base of you absolute

Comment: The blue is 15px wide but the button is off center by more than 15px.  Changing the width to 363px instead of the percentage still keeps the button off center. :/

Comment: @DavidW have a look at this example : http://jsfiddle.net/pux7q/2/ should be able to solve your issue

Comment: Hey Rain Man, this works well although in my situation, the button width varies depending on the text inside (theres multiple buttons on the page presented this way).  The answer below solved it best for me.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Wrapper element. 
Note that your image (363x363) is smaller than your column.

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/P7oYCAjc6d)**

### HTML

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">Search</a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#grid .btn-orange{
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#fcaf17;
  color:#fff;
  border:2px solid white;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 45px;
}
```

---

2nd Solution: ´left: 50%; margin-left: - <50% of element width>;´

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/cKoviQHHG6)**

```
#grid .btn-orange {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hell yeah!  Thank you so much!  Definitely something I'll remember forever.

Comment: No problem :) What I forgot to mention with the wrapping element: your button is by default a inline/inline-block element, you can set the wrapper to `text-align: center;` if so.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are being placed inside of grid elements and over a responsive image, you'll have to compensate for the viewports change. You can use a transform property and center the images on viewport change.

```css
#grid img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn.btn-orange {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 7px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fcaf17;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="grid" class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">Search</a> 
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=34&amp;txt=363%C3%97363&amp;w=363&amp;h=363">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">Search</a> 
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=34&amp;txt=363%C3%97363&amp;w=363&amp;h=363">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">Search</a> 
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=34&amp;txt=363%C3%97363&amp;w=363&amp;h=363">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```